# How to filter type-graphql subscription using context, instead of args?

Tags: typegraphql

I am trying to send notification to different users and want every user to see only his. I have already succeeded to do you with @Args.

Heres the subscribtion:

```
@Subscription(() => Notification, {
    topics: "NOTIFICATIONS",
    filter: ({ payload, args }: ResolverFilterData<Notification, NewNotificationArgs>) => {
        return payload.userId === args.userId;
    },
})
newNotification(
    @Root() notification: Notification,
    @Args() { userId }: NewRequestArgs
): Notification {
   return notification;
}
```

And the mutation:

```
@Mutation(() => Boolean)
async createNotification(
    @PubSub("NOTIFICATIONS") notifyAboutNewNotification: Publisher<Notification>
): Promise<Boolean> {
    const notification = await Notification.create({
        userId: <some id>,
        message: <some message>
    }).save();

    await notifyAboutNewRequest(notification);

    return true;
}
```

Now I want you use a userId, that I have stored in the context.req.session.userId as a cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I logged my context and It looks like I was getting the values, but undefined. You need to use the onConnect event to upgrade the context.

Links than helped me:
[Discussion](https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/issues/391)
[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuaVr7vFF5E&t=365s)

Answer (score 1):

`ResolverFilterData` contains payload, args, context and info. So you can access that by  `filter: ({ context }) => { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks man, you are right. I had already figured this out, but I forgot to update the post.